# gRPC socket closed message

Tags: python, go, grpc

I have developed a gRPC server in Go and a client in Python when the server task in the server takes too time, the following error occurred in the client and server runs without any error.

```
 raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Socket closed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1573373169.327520081","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Socket closed","grpc_status":14}"
```

Increasing timeout like this does not work and before timeout, around 4th sec, i got the error.

```
res = stub.Fake(
    fake_pb2.FakeRequest(
        **fake_request
    ),
    timeout=9
)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server's logs? Is it observing the request from the client?

Comment: @RichardBelleville
there is no error in the server

Answer (score 1):

the grpc status code 14 unavailable is mostly for transient errors and can be corrected with retrial mechanism.

Comment: for a special case, when the server task takes too much time, every time i see this error

Comment: the retry here is to throw away the connection and reconnect? I would expect the python grpc library to do that

Comment: @MartinKosicky I believe it does. I've seen some status code 14 UNAVAILABLE in my logs, that do not cause calling code to fail. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/11154